# How can I make an array of [anyType] in laravel schema builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, schema

Let's say I have a user schema, which will have "hobbies" linked to it, as a string of arrays.

I recently switched from MongoDB to SQL so, my first thought was approaching it like Mongo, and make something like this;

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    hobbies: [String] });
```

So, I tried to implement the same logic to laravel schema builder like this;

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('username');
      $table->string('password');
      $table->array(string('hobbies'));  //array(string("test")) is just a mock syntax, I just researched how can I implement an array type here and learned that I can't
```

Now I thought about two solutions, one is, find a way to implement it as an array somehow,
or, since the schemabuilder doesn't support putting an array type here, this is not the best logic I can use and I need to find another way of adding my "user" schema a "hobbies" array. (Only thing I could think was creating a "hobbies" schema and using eloquent relationship to bind them together, but that doesn't seem too practical)

Answer (score 0):

The *best* way would be to use [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships). I am not sure why it will not be practical in your case.

In your particular case, a `User` can have many `Hobby` and a `Hobby` can also belong to many `User`.

This is how your relationships would look like:

```
// in App\User.
public function hobbies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Hobby::class);
}

// in App\Hobby
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

You'd need to define your foreign keys accordingly in the two tables you have. Additionally, a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) needs a third table. In your case it would be called: `hobby_user`

To access a user's hobby, you'd just do something like this:

```
App\User::find(1)->hobbies;
```

While you could also save the hobbies as a string (.. or [JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#columns)), it might become a hassle later on if you want to do queries, reporting and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a JSON column to store an array.

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('username');
      $table->string('password');
      $table->json('hobbies');
```

Then on the model you can cast this column to an array each time you retrieve it automatically.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'hobbies' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, more common practice with relational databases is to create an additional table to store relationship between users and hobbies.
If you will need any sorting, searching, cascade deleting / updating and etc. it's more practical to create a many-to-many relation instead of storing as array.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.

I thought creating another schema/migration "hobbies" and then binding them with user > hasMany > hobbies but creating a schema with only one column (string) seemed a little bit odd, so I told myself "there's probably a better way even though this will work". If you're saying this is an ideal way to solve this I'll use the eloquent solution.

Cheers

Comment: You are welcome. It prevents many problems, for example duplicating of information, which leads to another set of problems. E.g. if users share the same hobby and then you need to rename this hobby, you will have to update all these users. But when you got a separate table for hobbies, all you need is to just update one row that will affects all linked users. If you just switched from NoSQL database to relational databases, you might want to read more about database design patterns, especially database normalization practices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **json** field (MySql support it out of the box),

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

see here the laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

maybe this will help you too

https://eloquentbyexample.com/course/lesson/lesson-9-json

Answer (score 0):

The array datatype is not present in all database systems. So you have to do the following method:
You could use **json->('')** method like following manners:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('username');
      $table->string('password');
      $table->json('hobbies');
```

And then your `user` model user property like.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $xyz= [
    'hobbies' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Comment: This won't work. There's no property `$xyz` defined in Laravel Models.